# VB.NET: Set combobox text from column in DB, but set value from different column

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am new at this and I could not find the answer in my hours-long search, so...

Can anyone educate me on how I can get a combobox to show text from one column in a database, but pass a different value when selected - VB.NET?

eg - I have a combo box that shows a column of names, and in the same table there is a column of numbers.  I want the name to be displayed in the combo box, but a value from a different column with numbers to be passed along to the query when selected.

This populates the combo box:

```
       Private Sub GetTeamMembers()
    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT distinct ACCPIN.CPIN, (CFIRST + CLAST) as TMNAME " & _
                  " FROM         ACCDTL LEFT OUTER JOIN " & _
                  " ACCPIN ON ACCDTL.CPIN = ACCPIN.CPIN " & _
                  " Order by TMNAME")

    ''Add to combo box
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(SQL.Exception) Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows
            cbxTeamMembers.Items.Add(dr("CPIN").ToString)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

So, CPIN is the column that holds the value that I want passed into the next query.  But I want to be able to show the column "TMNAME" in the combo box, but pass the value CPIN when I select the text in the combo box.

This runs using the current combobox selection:

```
    Private Sub cbxTeamMembers_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbxTeamMembers.SelectedIndexChanged
    GetTMAccess(cbxTeamMembers.Text)
End Sub
```

...And then:

```
Private Sub GetTMAccess(ByVal TeamMember As String)



    ''Run Query for access group pins
    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT ACCPIN.CFIRST AS FIRSTNAME " & _
                  ", ACCPIN.CLAST AS LASTNAME " & _
                  ", ACCPIN.CPIN AS PIN " & _
                  ", ACCPIN.CSHIFT AS SHIFT " & _
                  ", ACCPIN.CRANK AS TMRANK " & _
                  ", ACCDTL.CACCESSID AS ACCESS " & _
                  "FROM ACCDTL INNER JOIN " & _
                  "ACCPIN ON ACCDTL.CPINID = ACCPIN.CPIN " & _
                  "WHERE (ACCDTL.CPIN = '" & TeamMember & "') " & _
                  " ORDER BY FIRSTNAME")



    ''Halt & Report on errors
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SQL.Exception) Then MsgBox(SQL.Exception) : Exit Sub

    ''Fill The Datagridview with the query results
    If SQL.RecordCount > 0 Then
        dvgTMAccess.DataSource = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0)

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bind the control and set the `DisplayMember` to the name of the column whose values you want displayed and you set the `ValueMember` to the name of the column whose values you want returned by the `SelectedValue` property of the `ComboBox`.  In your case, that presumably means this:

```
With cbxTeamMembers
    .DisplayMember = "TMNAME"
    .ValueMember = "CPIN"
    .DataSource = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0)
End With
```

Note that fact that the `DataSource` is set last, which is not essential but is advisable.  This:

```
GetTMAccess(cbxTeamMembers.Text)
```

would then become this:

```
GetTMAccess(cbxTeamMembers.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: This is actually better. I'm not sure why I've been doing it the way I posted. Have `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` always been available for comboboxes?

Comment: So this is close to what I need, but now I get an error that the value of GetTMAccess(cbxTeamMembers.SelectedValue) is DBNull.  This happens when I launch the form, after I changed GetTMAccess(cbxTeamMembers.Text) to GetTMAccess(cbxTeamMembers.SelectedValue).

Comment: Does one or more of your `DataRows` contain NULL in that column?  By the way, you should change the way you build that command to use parameters rather than string concatenation.

Comment: Ah, yes - Look at that NULL value that is totally out of place in the table that I expected not to have NULLs

Comment: THANKS!

it's all good now.

And, I am literally just starting to learn to code, and some queries are over ODBC so I cannot use parameters - But I have used parameters successfully in a  couple of queries so far when dealing with SQL.  This query does go to SQL so I can actually add a list of SqlParameters.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an easier way to do this, but here is the method my colleagues implemented to solve this.

First, create a new class to store your values:

```
Public Class ComboItem
    Public Display As String
    Public Value As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal _display As String, ByVal _value As String)
        Display = _display
        Value = _value
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Display
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, when populating your comboboxes, do something like:

```
cbxTeamMembers.Items.Add(New ComboItem(dr("TMNAME"), dr("CPIN").ToString()))
```

And when retrieving them:

```
Dim result = DirectCast(cbxTeamMembers.SelectedItem, ComboItem).Value
```